# P-value calculation using simulation

Tags: r, simulation, p-value

Suppose that we would like to test whether the average miles-per-gallon of a car is equal to 22. Then H0: mu = 22 vs H1: mu =/= 22.
And suppose that the observed mean from the sample (observed test statistic, x_bar) is 20.09.
I would like to calculate a p-value using simulation.

In this case, do I need to simulate the sample means using the mean of 22 (mu)? Or 20 (x_bar)?

That is,

```
## Method 1:
samp <- replicate(n_samples, mean(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 22, sd = 3)))
two.sided.pval <- 2*min(c(prop(samp >= 20), prop(samp <= 20)))
```

or

```
## Method 2:
samp <- replicate(n_samples, mean(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 20, sd = 3)))
two.sided.pval <- 2*min(c(prop(samp >= 22), prop(samp <= 22)))
```

According to the definition of a p-value (i.e., a p-value is the probability of observing **a test statistic** as extreme as, or more extreme than, **the test statistic actually observed**, given that the null hypothesis is true), I think I need to get a sample using mu (=22) in order to get a null distribution.
That is, **the test statistic actually observed** is 20, while **a test statistic** is coming from a normal distribution with mean 22.

However, in the tutorial that I am reading now, the sample means were obtained using the observed mean (x_bar = 20) and, and it calculates a p-value depending on whether these sample means > mu (=22). (Basically Method 2)
Shouldn't it be the other way?

Comment: Are you sure you want a 2-sided null hypothesis? Most people wouldn't be bothered by having a higher gas mileage than advertised, but would want to know if it was distinctly lower. In either case, you should generate samples with a mean of 22 and the same sample size which yielded the 20.09 value. Then count what proportion are less than the observed test statistic of 20.09 for a 1-sided test, or what proportion are outside the range 22+/-(22-20.09) for a 2-sided test. Confidence or prediction intervals are centered on the sample mean, hypothesis testing is centered on the hypothesized mean.

Comment: @pjs I think that description might be an oversimplification. Both confidence intervals and  the h0 vs hA paradigm are associated with the Neyman-Pearson formulation of statistical tests. That stands in contrast to the Fisherian p-value formalism. At least that's my memory of reading the literature from that period. The way these concepts are taught these days is a muddled gemish of those two schools of thought. Then we have the Bayesian formulations of statistics.

Comment: @pjs Thanks for the reply. This is just a hypothetical example. My intention is to show how to explain the concept of the p-value based on the simulation scheme. Based on your comment, would Method 1 work?

Answer (score 0):

You ask: "test whether the average miles-per-gallon of a car is equal to 22. Then H0: mu = 22 vs H1: mu =/= 22." That implies that either an observed average over or below the hypothesis would constitute a rejection of H0. You want to know how often the H0: would be rejected when the sample mean was sample mean was 22.09. (**We are now reversing the roles of 22 as a H0 and 22.09 as an HA.**)

You have failed to give either a sample size for these simulation experiments or a sample standard deviation, but you have coded your efforts as though the specification was for samples of size 30 and the sd is 3. So let's run 1000 realizations of sampling with a mean of 22.09 and an sd of 3 and see how often the H) mean=22 is within the 95% two-sided CI.

```
> res <- replicate( 1000, 
+                                 { x <-  rnorm(30, 22.09, 3)
+                                            t.test(x, mu=22)$p.value })
> sum(res <0.05)
[1] 48
```

So 48 out of 1000 times or a p-value of 0.048, the Null Hypothesis would be rejected in that situation using the unspecified seed to the R random number generator.
That's a proportion of [1] 0.048 which is really really close to 0.05. That was a simulated rejection of the Null Hypothesis. So what happens the next couple of times we run the simulation?

```
> res <- replicate( 1000, 
+                                 { x <-  rnorm(30, 22.09, 3)
+                                            t.test(x, mu=22)$p.value })
> sum(res <0.05)
[1] 65    # p-value accepted
> res <- replicate( 1000, 
+                                 { x <-  rnorm(30, 22.09, 3)
+                                            t.test(x, mu=22)$p.value })
> sum(res <0.05)
[1] 62   # p-value again accepted
```

Those both "fail" to reject the Null Hypothesis. So we are really close to the "edge" of deciding whether the H0 is rejected or not assuming the parameters that were specified (mean=22) and those assumed (n=30 and sd=3). I don't know whether this is a homework assignment or not. And I don't know what perspective (Fisherian, NP, or Bayesian) your prof might be promulgating, but I think this is a "useful" answer in demonstrating the duality of the "ideal/theoretical" and the "simulated" approaches to statistical computation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, your explanation contains the use of the t.test function, which I am reluctant to use. My intention is to show how to explain the concept of the p-value based on the simulation scheme.